# Регулярные выражения. Поиск и замена тегов переноса строк с указанием кол.во замен

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не выходит составить р.в., с указанием кол.во замен.
Задача: найти и удалить от трех и более `<br />` подряд, если `<br />` начало и конец строки.

```
$str = "<p>стр.1</p><br />
стр.2<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
конец<br />
и для верности <p> <br /> </p>
<br /> 
";`
```

Пишу `$str = preg_replace('/(^<br\s\/>$){3,}/imsu',"", $str);` не работает 3 и более.

Так матчит только 1 бр но не 2 и не 3 `/(^<br\s\/>$){1,}/uims`
 А с 2 `(^<br\s\/>$){2,}` вообще не находит.

Подскажите пта., как правильно указать кол.во совпадений. Без группировки `(...)` ошибка, а со скобками `(...){3,}` не работает.

И еще вопрос, почему preg_replace ругается на флаг g — глобальный поиск   `"/regexp/imug"`

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "*если `<br />` начало и конец строки*"? В вашем примере что именно должно найтись, какой фрагмент?

Comment: Строка начинается с тега `<br />` первый символ  в стр. `<` между ними br / последний `>`

Comment: И где тут "начало строки"?

Comment: Ещё раз: что вы подразумеваете под "начало стр." и "конец стр"? Символы перевода строки до и после бр или что-то ещё? Сформулируйте точней. В вашем примере начало строки - это `<p>стр.1`, а конец - `</p>
<br />`

Comment: наверное я не правильно выразился, имелось ввиду перевод каретки.  Где после `<br />` спец символ ¶ &para; пара

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, вы пропустили обработку переводов строк после `<br />`:

[`/(<br\s*\/>\s*){3,}/`](https://regex101.com/r/kL3dP2/1)

Если же под "начало/конец строки" имеется в виду, что:

1. первый БР должен находиться или в начале тестируемой строки, или после символа перевода строки
2. последний БР должен завершать тестируемую строки или находиться перед символом перевода строки

то:

[`/(^(<br\s*\/>\s*){3,}$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/pV4tO3/1)

(флаг `s` там не нужен, затесался...)

Comment: вот так `(<br\s*\/>\s*){3,}` работает, спасибо всем кто ответил. Не пойму почему в конце `\s*` - пробельный символ а `*`Ноль или более . Получается ноль или более пробелов или повторение всего выражения?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько знаю, в PHP нету флага g, preg_replace и так заменяет все вхождения, если отсутствует последний параметр limit, либо равен -1.

Пробуйте так: `/(\<br\s\/\>){1,}/m`

> Так матчит только 1 бр но не 2 и не 3 `/(^<br\s\/>$){1,}/uims` А с 2
>   `(^<br\s\/>$){2,}` вообще не находит.

Вы в обоих выражениях ставите ^ и $, но в вашей тестовой строке теги br не начинаются с новой строки. Когда вы в коде переносите строку, это не означает, что в том месте, где перенос, будет ее конец. В том месте, где перенос, есть только метасимвол \n, больше ничего. Соответственно с флагом m должно все работать.

Comment: с флагом m не работает, но все равно спасибо за пояснение

Comment: Странно, попробуйте поиграться с вашей регуляркой здесь: regex101.com